# Twilio Video API Emit Custom Event to all Participants (javascript)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The documentation of Twilio states that it allows certain events to be retrived/binded, e.g, `participantConnected`, `participantDisconnected`. There are certain cases that the supported list of events is not enough, and it is required to send custom element (e.g, `my_custom_event`) to all currently connected participants.

A typical case is a host admin wants to mute a certain participant for ALL OTHER participants - he could trigger an event `requestAudioMuted` of the targeted `user_id` to all other participants.

I tested with the JS API:

```
room.on("myevent", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
        
room.emit("myevent", {a:1, b:2, user_id: 3});
```

It only works locally, and event is not received remotely.

Is there any available Twilio API that support the above (emit remotely) function? Or I have to build my own socket server for it?

Comment: This might work https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api#overview